# I can not update Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```rb
rails c
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/dayanov-sa in PATH, mode 040777
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         ... 4099 levels...
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

I tried to update via:

```rb
bundle update rails
gem install rails -v 5.0.2
gem update rails
```

```
Rails 4.2.0 version
ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-linux]
```

I get a lot of errors when running rails. I looked on the Internet that I need to upgrade, but without success

Comment: "How do I fix all of the upgrade deprecations and errors?" is a very broad topic, and unsuitable for StackOverflow. Start by going through the official upgrade guide, and feel free to ask a **specific** question on StackOverflow if you get stuck.

Comment: As for the question: "How do I upgrade rails?", I would suggest starting by updating the line in your `Gemfile` to: `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'` and then run `bundle update rails`.

Comment: @TomLord ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command rails,

Comment: I didn't say to run `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'` in the console. I said to write that line *in the `Gemfile`*. In your project, there is a file called `Gemfile`. Open it, find the line that mentions `rails`, and change it like I showed above.

Answer (score 1):

**Rails-4** prefers Ruby 2.0 and requires 1.9.3 or newer. **Rails-5** requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.

Your Rails version is quite old, upgrade it with,

```
gem upgrade rails
```

If you already have a Rails project you should,

1. Specify the desired version in your Gemfile
2. Run `bundle install` / `bundle update`
3. Run `rails app:update`

better you follow [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command upgrade

Comment: @HackeXe Specify the desired version in your Gemfile (e.g. gem 'rails', '~> 5' ) &  try `rails app:update`

Comment: ``` Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.2)

    leaflet-rails was resolved to 1.5.1, which depends on
      rails (>= 4.2.0)

    react-rails (~> 1.6.0) was resolved to 1.6.2, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.2)

    spork-rails was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Your version of `spork-rails` is incompatible with rails 5. So you'll need to update that library too, in order to upgrade rails.

Comment: @TomLord The fact is that I updated it to 4.0.0. When I do a bundle update, it tells me that it is version 4.0.0. When I change the version of rails ~> 5.0.0 it gives me an error that the version is not compatible

Comment: @HackeXe The error message states: **spork-rails was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on rails (>= 3.0.0, < 5)**. You cannot use spork-rails 4.0.0 with rails 5. You need to upgrade it further.

Comment: In fact, I just looked for you -- it seems this is an old abandoned project. Even the [latest version](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails/blob/0dd45e59d3237b4c8f9efc215b46d9c07072a95e/spork-rails.gemspec#L27) is not marked as compatible with rails 5. There has been an [open issue for 3 years](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails/issues/28) about it. So unfortunately, it seems you'll either need to add compatibility yourself, or find an open-source fork of the project that's done this already, or update the code to not use the gem.